How to link headers with gcc
I am working on an embedded project right now. A considerable part of the code is generic C (without any ties to the hardware) and can be run on a normal x86 PC. I would like to tests these parts on my PC, so that I can run it through valgrind.
The problem is ... linking.
The project is structured as following (I cannot change this):
lib
  util.c
  ...
include
  lib
    util.h
    logging.h
    ...
  ...
...
test
  testrunner.py
  tests
    test1.c
    ...

In util.c we include both #include "lib/util.h" and #include "lib/logging.h".
Now I would like to use the util inside my testX.c files (No CMake).
Issue 1: How can I successfully link both the source and header files? I obviously I only want the util included and not any other source/header files.
Issue 2: Whats the best way to handle the fact that util depends on logging (Which is currently just implementing asserts). Would it be the easiest to just write a new logging.h for my PC and link against that?
Edit:
The solution I found was to just explicitly tell gcc where the header files are. gcc -I../include -Iinclude ..., this way it prioritizes my x86 version of logging.h (in inlcude) instead of the embedded one (in ../include) and it doesn't complain that util.c cannot find lib/util.h.
...
test
  Makefile
  include/lib/logging.h
  ...



You don't link header files. You compile the source files and then link the resulting object files together.

you need to make the object file of the util.c and then link it while compiling of tests.

issue 2: the best way will be to make one step depend on other step. yeah. in general there is only one way to do it.

issue 1: what of the source files you want to link? the, what? what header files you want to include?

i've scrolled though your questions. you seem to know scripts, bash etc. you seem to use complicated makefiles. are you mocking us?

@user14063792468 linking was indeed the wrong word, sry.
I just need to import all functions specified in the header file so that i can call the functions & test them.

@user14063792468 if you scrolled through enough of my questions you should have noticed that I am trying a lot of different things so my actual knowledge is relatively shallow.
And if your talking about that makefile bs I was doing that too was just trying out some stuff too see how far I can go. I'm now using python for that since I've realized make isn't made for this.
(wouldn't one use an alt account for these things?)
(why are u stalking me :eyes:)
(If I would have known bash&make well I would have never asked these questions...)

i meant that i do not get your wording. the usage of "the" article. the files. what files. what is what and where.

lol, sry. it is just my experience that if a person uses scripts in makifile steps, then the person should know basics and beyond. it is just my logic. no need eyes, im sorry.

@user14063792468 all good. the internet is a strange place.

@user14063792468 "the" files means I just want to be able to call all functions that are declared in util.h and defined in util.c

Since you have a /lib/ folder I assume you build a library that is then linked to the final binary. That is a problem for logging or anything that will differ between an embedded build and the test cases. So I suggest splitting the lib into the hardware related stuff and the generic stuff. So for example a libutil and liblog. Libutil depends on the functions in liblog but now the test cases can link in a liblog-test with the same functions but using for example printf() to log instead of whatever the embedded system uses. Note: Both liblog and liblog-test would use the same logging.h header.

Automatic linking
Compiling with gcc you are implicitly linking source files with headers if you don't specify any option.
Here an example:
main.c:
#include "head.h"

int main(void) {
    printf("This is the main.\n");
    someFunction();
    return 0;
}

external.c:
#include "head.h"

void someFunction() {
    printf("This is a function.\n");
}

head.h
#ifndef HEAD_H
#define HEAD_H

#include <stdio.h>

extern void someFunction();

#endif // HEAD_H

You can compile and link these files using this simple Makefile:
all:
    gcc -Wall main.c external.c -o program.exe

clean:
    rm program.exe

It creates program.exe which can be tested executing it: ./program.exe. You will see the output:
This is the main.
This is a function.

Manual linking (solution for issue 1)
Contrarwise, gcc compiles, but doesn't automatically link object files if you specify -c option. Then, you can separate compilation by linking. You will need a Makefile like this:
all:
    gcc -Wall -c main.c external.c 
    gcc main.o external.o -o program.exe
    rm main.o external.o

clean:
    rm program.exe

Here, first gcc compiles source files and creates object files. Then, it links object files creating the executable.
Conclusion
Thanks this approach you can obtain what you asked for. You can create the executable from a subset of source files. After compiling the whole program, you can decide to link a subset of generated object files.
Issue 2 isn't so clear... if you mean to break up dependencies, you cannot do this because, if the program uses some external definitions, it must be able to find it.

Finally, consider that rewrite code from zero to test it is a very bad idea because it drives your software to unexpected bugs. You should be able to test your code as is.

I am currently including lib/util.h inside my util.c so when running gcc -c test1.c .../util.c it complains that the header is not found (rightfully so). But I kinda need it to include it, so the actual embedded program can find the references?

@FrontedC The program can find references if you run gcc test1.o .../util.o to link your objs. Headers are excluded while you compile with gcc with the option -c. Even if you included the header in the file util.c, if you do not link using the command which I suggested, then the program can't find references.


The problem is ... linking.

No, I don't think it is.  The linker will link whatever object files and libraries you tell it to do, so you can choose the ones you want.
And that has nothing whatever to do with header files.  By the time you get around to linking, if you do, the compiler has already made all the use of headers that it is going to do.  The resulting object files are inputs to the link, which is insensitive to details of how they were built or from which sources and headers.

In util.c we include both #include "lib/util.h" and #include "lib/logging.h".

As long as you do that, unconditionally, both headers will be used whenever you compile util.c.  And then their role is done.  After that point, they make no further contribution to the build.

Issue 1: How can I successfully link both the source and header files? I obviously I only want the util included and not any other source/header files.

No, it's not at all obvious what you want.  But what you get is all the headers #included, directly or indirectly, by your C sources used during compilation, and no others.  Then you get whatever object files and libraries you ask for included in the link, and no others.
Moreover, if your headers are in fact structured appropriately -- only macros and declarations, no object or function definitions -- then including headers that you don't strictly need should not itself present any issue.
Overall, unless you're doing something you shouldn't, this is a non-issue.

Issue 2: Whats the best way to handle the fact that util depends on logging (Which is currently just implementing asserts). Would it be the easiest to just write a new logging.h for my PC and link against that?

Again, header dependencies are not a link issue themselves.  As it pertains to logging.h, the potential genuine issues here revolve around using macros from logging.h that produce behaviors you don't want exercised by the tests, such as calling functions defined in some other C source file, or maybe even just evaluating the assertions you mentioned.  Mechanisms for dealing with that sort of thing depend on the details, but here's a good and pretty common approach:

Put all the logging behavior in actual functions, not macros, defined in their own C source file.  Put corresponding declarations in your logging.h.

Provide a different set of logging functions with the same signatures in or alongside the test harness, which implement the logging (non-)behavior you want for the tests.  This would involve C source files, not any additional header.  Such functions are called "stubs" if they do nothing, and whether they are stubs or not, substitute functions used in support of unit testing are often called "mocks".

When you link the regular program you use the object file (not header) containing the compiled regular logging functions in the link.  When you link the unit tests you instead use the object file containing the compiled mocks in the link.  These alternatives are controlled by the details of the link command you use.


The above also applies to any other dependencies your util.c might have on functions defined elsewhere.  You can link in either the regular versions of such functions or mocks, as serves your testing purposes.

Linking is the process of relocation all already compiled compilation units into a single executable.  You cannot link a header file, because you have not compiled it previously.  Header files (more if they include generic code) are included in compilation units where all the code they have is read by the compiler and compiled as part of the compilation unit (source suffixed with .c) that specifically #includes it.
Generic C code normally is handled in .h files to be included and adapted to the proper compilation unit environment, by providing appropiate types that will be used in that compilation.  If you want it to be used by a different compilation unit, it will need to be included again in that compilation unit, but first adapting the new data types (the ones generic) to the new compilation unit.  And so on.
If you need your generic code not be generic (this means, your code will be instantiated with a single set of types and reused in several compilation units) then the solution consists in creating a special compilation unit with the set of parameters needed for that implementation, and generate a compilation unit that declares all generic functions already instantiated for the types and constants that the code will specify.
